# Knowing the number of searches in playstore

Tags: android

How can I know if how many have search my application in google playstore and fetch it by using codes? Especially if they use keyword search. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that Google provides this information

Comment: Even if it is my app I am going to look at?

Comment: @monte I haven't seen any information like that either.

Comment: What can you suggests?